# Importing certificates: "Keystore contains a certificate with an alias that conflicts with a certificate already in the organization."

Tags: namedcredentials, certificates

I'm trying to deploy changes that include Named Credentials from one sandbox to another. In order to do that, all the certificates used by my Named Credentials need to be in the target sandbox at the time of deployment.

I'm trying to use the Export to Keystore/Import from Keystore feature to migrate all the missing certificates, but I get the following error:

> Keystore contains a certificate with an alias that conflicts with a
> certificate already in the organization.

There is indeed a duplicate certificate in the target sandbox. But I can't just delete it, since it is tied to existing Named Credentials in that sandbox.

It doesn't appear that you can simply export/import individual certificates -- it seems to be all or nothing.

Am I missing something? How can I get these changes deployed?

Comment: Change the cert's alias in keystore prior to import, see steps in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338348&type=1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by renaming the existing certificates in the target sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

rename alias when you reference it to a lower case :
For example : myCertificateALias --> mycertificatealias

I used key store and it was generated with lower case and that worked for me